# Data Transferring is Slow – from Backend to Front-End

Tags: database, performance, database-connection, frontend

==> **My System** :

Processer - `Xeon 8 Cores @ 3.8GHz`

RAM -`20 GB`

Storage – `11 HDD SAN - RAID 5 configured I/O Rate – 260 MB/s`

Network – `Cisco 1 Gbps Intranet`

Front End – `Using C#.Net desktop Application, PL/SQL Developer (write PL/SQL)`

==> **Database** :

`Oracle 11g` (11.2.0.3) Standard Edition on `Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit` (OLTP use)

Have more than 60 tables.

Most tables have above 8 million records

Reports are generated which output gives approx. 5 millions records and send to front end.

==> **My Problem** :

Data fetched and processed on complex query is good enough.

But when procedure or query execute which output may have millions of data

Sending to front end or pl/sql developer(test procedure/query)

My problem starts here,

Oracle database processed data (no high cpu or hdd usage on server side)

Network usage show `2-3 MB per second` transfer rate

Data starts coming into Client side slow like `800 records` in 1 second.

Its millions of data to come, so taking too much time to complete data arrive on front end.

So management is not happy with this, its report on front side taking minutes to display.

How can I improve this? I need faster data on Client side.

Comment: How do you access to database? What is your SQL?

Comment: Any DB which is outputting millions of records will not be faster in any case. If you need that amount of data then whatever you are doing is not designed properly. try to process it in DB using SP. for outputting data faster try "zerocopy" technique. Not sure it will help but can have a look.

Comment: @Fumu7 PL/SQL developer app and a c#.net in house desktop application

Answer (score 0):

In Any Report user wont and will never see all 5M rows... then whats the point to pull so much of data?
Do all agreggation/Header/Footer data calc in db itself & take only upto 100's of rows back to UI/App,
Desing needs to be worked out properly.... Nither DB/APP/NW is an issue.. they are well & good !

Comment: But management want that way. So we ha e to write procedure that way which outs lots of data. Bcz on front end pivoting and grouping done as client demad.